# Spring JPA Hibernate query cache doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Boot 1.4.1 AND spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

When query my custom method like 'findByName(String name)' it's not cache.

But when query default method like 'findOne(Interger id)' it's work.

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
    Author findByName(String name);
}
```

Tests:

```
public class RepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
        authorRepository.save(new Author("admin"));

        // ***Not work. query **5** times.
        Author author = authorRepository.findByName("admin");
        author = authorRepository.findByName("admin");
        author = authorRepository.findByName("admin");
        author = authorRepository.findByName("admin");
        author = authorRepository.findByName("admin");

        // ***It's work. query **1** times.
        Author author = authorRepository.findOne(1);
        author = authorRepository.findOne(1);
        author = authorRepository.findOne(1);
        author = authorRepository.findOne(1);
        author = authorRepository.findOne(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
    @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value ="true") })
    Author findByName(String name);
}
```

Should do the trick. (Note: the `@Repository` is not needed because you already extend CrudRepository)